# Past tense of なし in Classical Japanese?

Tags: grammar, classical-japanese

Is it なしかりたらず as a usual し adjective? Or is it something weirder? I need this for a skit.

Comment: How about「なかりけり」?

Comment: Which kind are you refering to ? http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%96%87%E8%AA%9E%E4%BD%93#.E7.A8.AE.E9.A1.9E

Comment: 終止形 of course, in usual Classical Japanese. Not *Old Japanese* (上代日本語)...

Comment: @EricDong Are you sure that you want past negative? What would that mean for nasi? Consider modern atui "hot". Past negative would be atukunakatta "was not hot". Using the same pattern, modern past negative for nai is nakunakatta. What are you trying to say? It may help if you provide a few lines of the skit that you are creating. Note that the suggested nakarikeri (=nakatta) is past, not past negative. Also nakariki is recollectional past, not past negative.

Comment: I was trying to say "this thing did not exist".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 古典文法は得意ではないですが、「なかりき」又は「なかりけり」だと思います。
>   自分が体験したことを話すときは「なかりき」、人に聞いたことを話すときは「なかりけり」だそうです。

Comment: I see that you used the "quote" markup.  Is this a quote?  If so, where is it from?

Comment: @snailplane A coworker.